# ASP.NET Identity "new item scaffolded" not shown

Tags: asp.net, identity, scaffolding

I want to add identity scaffolded item to my project (Visual Studio 2022 - ASP.NET Wep Application .Net Framework).

But, I cannot add identity by using Add > New Scaffolded Item, because there is no identity selection as shown in the screenshot here. How can I add it ? Thank you.

I am trying to add to my project register and login and roles for users and admin

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrBIV.png)